# iTunes install error 45075 on Windows 8.1

Tags: itunes, error, windows

I've attempted to install iTunes on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit for the first time. I downloaded the latest `iTunes64Setup.exe` from Apple's website, and the install seemingly completes without error.

However, when I run iTunes, I get the error "A required iTunes component is not installed" with error number 45075, and then iTunes closes.

The install process didn't involve any component selection/deselection, so I'm not sure what caused this. Also, this is a clean install of Windows so I don't imagine existing installs are interfering.

I've tried:

- repairing the install
- uninstall/reinstall
- [this advice](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5791079?tstart=0) to uninstall all other Apple components (Bonjour, Quicktime, etc), before reinstalling. However, in my case there are no other existing Apple components that might be interfering.

Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: This may help: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which is a variant on [this advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/itunes-error-45075/5bb46990-a758-4dfe-84be-d943be8565d3), which suggests extracting the files and installing the components manually in a particular order.

1. Extract `iTunes64Setup.exe` (I used 7-zip)
2. Run `AppleApplicationSupport64.msi`
3. Run `iTunes64.msi`

Success! Now iTunes opens, and stays open.